# Как убрать перенаправления в файле .htaccess которые мешают ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess

Вот мой ajax запрос:

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/' + url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: name + '_f=1' + str,
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
```

вот что у меня в .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /css/([^\/]+).css$ css/$1.css [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

в файле register.php куда ajax отправляет запросы:

```
else if ($_POST['register_f']) {
        message('регистрация');
}
```

в итоге вместо фразы 'регистрация' я получаю html код со страницы index.php

success result содержит код страницы, а не ответ из php

я уточнил что проблема в том что в .htacccess прописано все запросы редиректить на одну единственную страницу - главную,
вот и вопрос, как мне исправить это?
может добавить какие то исключения, но как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Последняя строчка в файле .htaccess, вот эта директива RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA], отвечает за редирект, она переписывает любые запросы на index.php. Но условия перед ней, указывают на то, что она будет выполняться только если запрос будет идти к файлу -f или директории -d, которые физически не существуют на сервере. То есть в вашем случае почему то при запросе не видно файла register.php. Сделайте 2 вещи: 
во первых, проверьте переменную url, которую вы вставляете в путь запроса и весь путь запроса целиком, возможно, там что-то неправильно, или не нужен первый слэш.
Во вторых, проверьте лежит ли физически этот файл в директории на сервере куда вы обращаетесь с запросом.

Надеюсь что-то из этого вам поможет!)

Comment: Спасибо! да, там глупая ошибка была в пути, хотя я и в .htaccess добавил в исключения запросы, но ошибка была просто в пути

Comment: Всегда не мешает проверять промежуточные данные, так Вы убеждаетесь, что все работает правильно. Очень рад, что у Вас все получилось)